# Oracle 12cR2 could'nt import

Tags: linux, oracle, import, oracle12c

I'm trying to import my dump file to 'orcalpdb'(12c plugindb), but I got someting problem...

I need you help. :(

My problem

```
[oracle@demo ~]$ imp ASSP/xxxx@orclpdb file= /home/oracle/assp.dmp  fromuser=ASSP touser=ASSP

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Apr 14 13:52:09 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


IMP-00058: ORACLE error 12537 encountered
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

listener.log

```
14-APR-2017 17:23:24 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus@demo)(HOST=demo)(USER=oracle))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=11958)) * establish * orclpdb * 12518
TNS-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00517: Lost contact
    Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe
```

but I tried to use 'tnsping orclpdb' ,and it is successful

```
[oracle@demo ~]$ tnsping orclpdb

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 14-APR-2017 13:51:24

Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)))
OK (0 msec)
```

My Configuration (tnsnames.ora , listener.ora , sqlnet.ora )are on blew.

tnsnames.ora :

```
LISTENER_ORCLPDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORCLPDB  =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oradb12clinux.globeunion.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =  
(SID_LIST =  
  (SID_DESC =  
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
  (SID_NAME = orcl)
  )
)
```

sqlnet.ora

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT, HOSTNAME)
```

My Environment :

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3

Oracle 12cR2

Comment: Your listener config says it's on 1539, so do you have some other non-Oracle process using 1521?

Comment: thank you for your anser.

I tried to change 1539 to1521 , but it 's still worng. QAQ

Comment: I just only one  database  on my server.